# Inserting data into database php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a website and i want to insert data into a phpmyadmin table from a form (method="post") it didn't work i'm connected to the data base but when i type stuff in my form it's not inserted in the table, here's my php part:

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=Database", $username, $password);
    echo 'Connected to database';
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{    
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$nom = $_POST['nom'];
$prenom =$_POST['prenom'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO client (nom, prenom, email,password,type)
                    VALUES ($nom, $prenom, $email, $password , $type)"; 
}
$conn->connection = null;
?>
```

Comment: You are missing quotes around your values but better yet use prepared statements.Also you are not running that query anywhere

Comment: where did you learn this? There's no pint of using PDO if you not gonna use prepared statements

Comment: Also, writing a query in a text literal does not pass it to the database for execution. [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: And some sensible code indentation allows you and us to actually read the code. ___And see unnecessary `}` symbols___

Comment: Oh and `phpMyAdmin` is a tools written in PHP. `MYSQL` is a database managment system

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not gonna comment much, there's still a lot of learning and
>   practice that you need to do. Please take your time and go through
>   this blog, read and practice from it, do not rush take your time
>   https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Your code should be looking similar to the one below :

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=Database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}


$nom      = $_POST['nom'];
$prenom   = $_POST['prenom'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$type     = $_POST['type'];


try {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO client (nom, prenom, email,password,type)   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    if ($stmt->execute(array(
        $nom,
        $prenom,
        $email,
        $password,
        $type
    ))) {

        echo "Data inserted";
    } else {

        echo "could not insert";
    }

}
catch (Exception $ex) {

    error_log($ex->getMessage());

}


?>
```

Comment: sh!t!! yhea u write I was in a hurry, will fix tht thanks